# How to avoid breaking word in the end of line using pre tag in html / css?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, pre

I'm using `<pre>` tag in `HTML` but how to make a long word jump to the next line instead to break it in two parts ?

This is a simple example [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pitmit/ub8fstbu/)

In my example i need the word : `contains` to go to the next line automatically and not cut on two

```css
pre.test {
    width: 11em; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre;

}
```

```html
<pre class="test"> This paragraph contains a very long word: 
thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to your CSS like: https://jsfiddle.net/ub8fstbu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: pre-line;`:

```css
pre.test {
    width: 11em; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<pre class="test"> This paragraph contains a very long word: 
thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</pre>
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)